# Value of variable altered by Text Field is not updated in Flat Button

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout, flatbutton

Here is the build function. The variable `newTaskTitle` which is initially null takes the value from the TextField. But this value is not reflected in the Flat Button widget. The value of `newTaskTitle` remains null at the FlatButton widget. Help me understand where I went wrong.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle = newText;
                print(newTaskTitle);
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                print(newTaskTitle);
                addTaskCallback(newTaskTitle);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

To clone the project, the partially completed code can be found here: https://github.com/vkmanojk/Flutter/tree/master/todoey_flutter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try declaring outside `build()` method, and calling `setState()` in `onChanged()`

Comment: @MohamedSayed I did try. The result is still the same. Also, I have used ```StateLess``` widget, so declaring a variable outside the method raises a warning and ```setState()``` is not possible.

Comment: Are you getting the words you type in the console ? that is when you use print ?

Comment: @KrishBhanushali Yes.

Comment: When the input text is hhh  -                                                                            
    ```I/flutter (32727): h
I/flutter (32727): hh
I/flutter (32727): hhh
I/flutter (32727): null
 ``` is the console output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Manoj I can see you have used stateless widget to do this task, And you are declaring your variable here :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String newTaskTitle;     <----- Here
```

So My answer is dont declare it here Please declare it as in global umm like this below your import

```
import 'material.dart';
String newTaskTitle;   <--- Here or anywhere outside the scope of Stateless widget
```

Now we usually prefer using Stateful widgets for the task like this.
Hope this works : )

Comment: Thank you @Krish.That does solve the issue. But I don't understand why creating a variable inside the build function does not work. It did work earlier before the recent updates. It would be highly appreciable if you could clarify. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for the appreciation I would get back to you soon. : )